# Groovy function with parameter

Tags: groovy, closures, categories

I have a class which is paring csv based file, but I would like to put a parameter for the token symbol. 
Please let me know how can I change the function and use the function on program.

```
class CSVParser{  
  static def parseCSV(file,closure) {  
        def lineCount = 0
        file.eachLine() { line ->  
            def field = line.tokenize(';')  
            lineCount++  
            closure(lineCount,field)  
        }  
    }  
} 


use(CSVParser.class) {  
    File file = new File("test.csv")  
    file.parseCSV { index,field ->  
        println "row: ${index} | ${field[0]} ${field[1]} ${field[2]}"  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add the parameter in between the `file` and `closure` parameters.

When you create a category class with static methods, the first parameter is the object the method is being called on so `file` must be first.

Having a closure as the last parameter allows the syntax where the open brace of the closure follows the function invocation without parentheses.

Here's how it would look:

```
class CSVParser{  
    static def parseCSV(file,separator,closure) {  
        def lineCount = 0
        file.eachLine() { line ->  
            def field = line.tokenize(separator)  
            lineCount++  
            closure(lineCount,field)  
        }  
    }  
} 

use(CSVParser) {  
    File file = new File("test.csv")  
    file.parseCSV(',') { index,field ->  
        println "row: ${index} | ${field[0]} ${field[1]} ${field[2]}"  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the separator as the second parameter to the `parseCSV` method:

```
class CSVParser{  
  static def parseCSV(file, sep, closure) {  
    def lineCount = 0
    file.eachLine() { line ->  
      def field = line.tokenize(sep)  
      closure(++lineCount, field)  
    }  
  }  
} 

use(CSVParser.class) {  
  File file = new File("test.csv")  
  file.parseCSV(";") { index,field ->  
    println "row: ${index} | ${field[0]} ${field[1]} ${field[2]}"  
  }  
}
```